# LEFT JOIN with latest record

Tags: mysql

I looked at several answers that seem to be a solution, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

My query below contains a left join to `jos_payplans_invoice` and `jos_payplans_transaction`. I need to get the latest invoice (`b.invoice_id`), and the latest transaction (`c.transaction_id`) for that invoice.

From my understanding, I need subqueries, but not sure how.

```
SELECT 
    a.subscription_id,
    b.invoice_id,
    c.transaction_id 
FROM jos_payplans_subscription AS a 
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_invoice AS b ON b.object_id = a.order_id 
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_transaction AS c ON c.invoice_id = b.invoice_id 
GROUP BY a.subscription_id
ORDER BY c.transaction_id DESC
```

Notice:
jos_payplans_invoice.object_id = jos_payplans_subscription.order_id

jos_payplans_subscription:

[image: jos_payplans_subscription]

jos_payplans_invoice:

[image: jos_payplans_invoice]

jos_payplans_transaction:

[image]

Comment: It's going to be really difficult for anyone to help you as-is. Remember that nobody here is familiar with your data-model (for example, how do you know which record is the latest?). You'll get better responses if you remove the parts of your query not relevant to your current issue, and if you include some representative sample data plus your expected results.

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Comment: If someone were to ask you to just get the latest transaction_id for each invoice_id in your `jos_payplans_transactions` table and nothing else, how would you do that?

Comment: @Dyvel -  Please share your table structure, table columns of three tables you mentioned in your ques. That will be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @Ishpreet : I have added my table structure :-)

Comment: @JoshEller I have simplified my example, and included my table structure, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There may be some opportunity for refactoring here (especially if you are on a newer version of mysql that supports window functions). This should get you in the ballpark though:

Get the last `transaction_id` for each `invoice_id`

```
SELECT transaction_id, invoice_id 
FROM jos_payplans_transactions jpt
WHERE create_date = 
    (
        SELECT max(create_date)
        FROM jos_payplans_transactions
        WHERE jpt.invoice_id = invoice_id
    )
```

Get the last `object_id` for each `order_id`:

```
SELECT invoice_id, object_id
FROM jos_payplans_invoice jpi
WHERE create_date = 
    (
        SELECT max(create_date)
        FROM jos_payplans_invoice
        WHERE jpi.object_id = object_id
    )
```

Put it all together:

```
SELECT
    a.subscription_id,
    b.invoice_id,
    c.transaction_id
FROM jos_payplans_subscription as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT invoice_id, object_id
            FROM jos_payplans_invoice jpi
            WHERE create_date = 
                (
                    SELECT max(create_date)
                    FROM jos_payplans_invoice
                    WHERE jpi.object_id = object_id
                )
        ) b on a.order_id = b.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT transaction_id, invoice_id 
            FROM jos_payplans_transactions jpt
            WHERE create_date = 
                (
                    SELECT max(create_date)
                    FROM jos_payplans_transactions
                    WHERE jpt.invoice_id = invoice_id
                )
        ) c on b.invoice_id = c.invoice_id;
```

Newer versions of Mysql (8.0+) can handle window functions, which will help improve performance here since only a single scan of each table is needed:

```
SELECT
    a.subscription_id,
    b.invoice_id,
    c.transaction_id
FROM jos_payplans_subscription as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT invoice_id, 
                object_id, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY create_date) as rn
            FROM jos_payplans_invoice jpi               
        ) b on a.order_id = b.object_id
            AND b.rn = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT transaction_id, 
                invoice_id ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_id ORDER BY create_date) as rn
            FROM jos_payplans_transactions jpt              
        ) c on b.invoice_id = c.invoice_id
            AND c.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution. I'm running MySQL 5.7 - Looks like it is working, but seems almost impossible to run - my query has been running for an hour now, and not finished :-O

Comment: I would guess some indexing would help. Do you have any indexes on these tables? Indexes on `create_date`, `object_id`, `invoice_id`, and `transaction_id` should help speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT 
    a.subscription_id,
    b.invoice_id,
    c.transaction_id 
FROM jos_payplans_subscription AS a 
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_invoice AS b ON b.invoice_id = (SELECT max(invoice_id) FROM jos_payplans_invoice WHERE object_id=a.order_id)
LEFT JOIN jos_payplans_transaction AS c ON c.transaction_id = (SELECT max(transaction_id) FROM jos_payplans_transaction WHERE invoice_id = b.invoice_id) 
GROUP BY a.subscription_id
ORDER BY c.transaction_id DESC
```

Let me know if it works for you.